How to implement trait function with rust ndarray parameters?
The trait have parameters with ndarray general Dimension.
I've tried to convert parameters to 1D array, since the data I'll cluster is 1D arrays of length 20-30. But that didn't work.
Then I searched for keywords like assert dimensions, see if the function prototype could equivalently providing me ArrayView1<f32>, but it seems that nobody else is trying this.
Can I handle hyper-parameter D for different dimensions separately? Or do I have to implement the function generically for any dimension? I have no idea how to compare array elements without know its dimension in advance.
use linfa_clustering::Dbscan;
use linfa_nn::{KdTree, distance::Distance};

#[derive(Clone)]
struct NonzSegMetric {}

impl Distance<f32> for NonzSegMetric {
    fn distance<D>(&self, a: ndarray::ArrayView<f32, D>, b: ndarray::ArrayView<f32, D>) -> f32 {
        // a.get(3);
        1.0 
    }   
}

fn main() {
    let clusters = Dbscan::params_with(20, NonzSegMetric {}, KdTree);
}

The data I want to cluster are 55000 1D array of length 20-30. I appreciate any help, maybe point out some mistakes I've made, some keyword for googling.
EDIT: The above code is correct.
I'm asking for help of implementing the distance function, I don't know how to get array elements without knowing its dimensions in advance.
eg. a.get(3) won't compile.
And if I'm not supposed to use a b this way, then I don't know how to get a b elements for my detailed implementation.

What's wrong with the code you posted? Does it fail to compile? With what error? Does it compile but fail to run? With what error? Does it compile and run but produce the wrong result? What did you expect and what did it produce instead? Please [edit] your question to add the missing details.

@Jmb I'm stuck in further implementing distance function. All I knew about ndarray was assuming the array having some specific dimension. But the distance function prototype is not presented that way. I'm familiar with ArrayView1 and the function is finally called with 1D array, but knows little about dynamic dimension.
